# How to exchange Azure Active Directory access token with one audience for another

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-ad-msal

I am wondering if it is possible to exchange an access token with one audience for an access token for another audience in using MSAL.NET in C#.

I have an application who gets an access token as input. The token is for the audience of https://management.core.windows.net/. Within this application, I will need to access some other azure resources like https://vault.azure.net and/or https://database.windows.net. Is it possible to use MSAL.NET to exchange the provided token for one with other audiences?

If this is not possible with MSAL.NET, what are some other options for doing this?

Comment: Which flow did you use to get the token? Why not simply get the token with other audiences again?

Comment: @joy The token is supplied by some user as an argument. This is the input I receive from the outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible.

Not only in MSAL.NET, but also in the whole Azure AD, there is no such way to exchange an access token with one audience for an access token for another audience.